# In neural networks, how to tell the feature which contributes the most to the output value?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a neural network which uses input features $N$, some input layers $L$ which predict a continuous variable $X$. Can we say which features or combination of 2 features of the initial $N$ features contribute the most to the change in $X$?

Example: Suppose I am trying to predict the house prices on basis of number of rooms, area of house, porch area, length, width.

Can I identify the feature $x$ or combination of 2 features that causes the most change in prices of house?

I was thinking of a brute force approach by varying one feature and keeping rest constant and see varies the prices the most. If there's a standard way, please share some resources to read.

Comment: Difficult topic. You cannot test as you describe, because parameters are interrelated. I would look into Automatic Relevance Detection (ARD) framework of McKay.

Comment: The R package NeuralNetTools has several functions with this goal in mind. The problem is that effects are not separable, as they are in a regression. So you'll have to adjust your thinking accordingly. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NeuralNetTools/index.html

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a statistics question than a specific programming one.  If you have your heart set on using neural nets an example using feature selection with Garson's algorithm is [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/variable-importance-in-neural-networks/).  Below I have provided the code that you can try.  Hopefully this can give you something to start with.

But please note this is only one possible answer.  There are many other approaches people have taken as this is an active area of research (neural networks are complex!).  There are very likely other methods that may be more suitable, more efficient, etc.  You may not want to even use neural nets (I don't know your specific reasons).  Depending on your data it may be better to use some alternative feature selection up front before the neural net.  A simple google scholar search for 'neural network feature selection' will return several papers on the matter.  There are many very strong opinions on the subject of neural networks so be warned there is no definitive answer out there.

```
# code from link noted above (slightly updated)
require(clusterGeneration)
require(nnet)

#define number of variables and observations
set.seed(2)
num.vars<-8
num.obs<-10000

#define correlation matrix for explanatory variables
#define actual parameter values
cov.mat<-genPositiveDefMat(num.vars,covMethod=c("unifcorrmat"))$Sigma
rand.vars<-mvrnorm(num.obs,rep(0,num.vars),Sigma=cov.mat)
parms<-runif(num.vars,-10,10)
y<-rand.vars %*% matrix(parms) + rnorm(num.obs,sd=20)

#prep data and create neural network
y<-data.frame((y-min(y))/(max(y)-min(y)))
names(y)<-'y'
rand.vars<-data.frame(rand.vars)
mod1<-nnet(rand.vars,y,size=8,linout=T)

require(devtools)

#import 'gar.fun' from beckmw's Github - this is Garson's algorithm
source_gist('6206737')

#use the function on the model created above
gar.fun('y',mod1)
```

Here is the output plot.  You can see there are both positive and negative values.  The negative and positive values reflect negative and positive relationships between the variable and the response variable.  [image: nnet variable importance plot]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Can you suggest some other methods (other than neural nets) which can be suitable to perform this task?

Comment: @ayush1723 How many variables do you have?  Are they all continuous or mixed with categorical?  Do your variables fit any distribution assumptions such as normality?  If your problem is similar to the 'house' example you describe, you likely could just do a basic multivariate regression model (which is easily accomplish in R if that is your desired language).  A bit more information is needed before I could give more of an answer.

Comment: @ayush1723, have you found your answer?

Comment: @cdterman :I found correlation between each input feature with the output parameter. I am not sure if its accurate. The problem I am working on has both categorical values as well as continuous feature. I am trying to convert the categorical ones into some continuous form because I don't know how to handle categorical data to answer this question. I'll try multivariate Regression model and will reply soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @cdeterman, do you know how we can extract the numerical values from gar.fun('y',mod1)?

Answer (score 0):

`caret` package offers variable importance for neural network models along with others. You can refer to this [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-76/topics/varImp) which says:

> **Neural Networks:** The method used here is based on Gevrey et al (2003), which uses combinations of the absolute values of the weights. For classification models, the class-specific importances will be the same.

It also includes feature selection by Recursive Feature:

> **Recursive Feature Elimination:** Variable importance is computed using the ranking method used for feature selection. For the final subset size, the importances for the models across all resamples are averaged to compute an overall value.

Here's what you can do :

```
library(caret)

# varimp
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
model <- train(y~., data=train, method="nnet",trControl=control)
imp<-varImp(model)
plot(imp)

# rfe
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
results <- rfe(train[,!colnames %in% c("y")],train$y, sizes=c(1:(ncol(train)-1), rfeControl=control)
 print(results)
# features selected 
predictors(results)
plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))
```